# jq: Assign Value to Variable then Use Variable in select in One Statement

Tags: bash, jq

Output from `curl` contains JSON and this is piped to `jq`.

Running this:

```
jq -r '.list[] | select(.dt > 1677812400) | .clouds.all'
```

get me several lines of integers which I then average by piping to `awk`

What I'd like to do is to substitute the value 1677812400 with one that I can obtain by running the same `curl` and then piping to this:

```
jq -r '.city.sunrise'
```

I appreciate that it could be done in two steps - (1) running the `curl|jq` and assigning the value to a shell var (2) using the var in the second `curl|jq`, but I am sure there is a way to do it all in one go.

I have tried:

```
jq -r --arg sunrise "$(jq -r '.city.sunrise')" '.list[] | select(.dt > ($sunrise|tonumber)) | .clouds.all'
```

but this yields precisely nothing, so I'm stuck.

If more detail is needed on the JSON I am happy to provide it.

Comment: Instead of `<<< $()` use `< <( )`

Comment: Sorry, had already removed the comment on second guess, thought you needed 2  curl's

Comment: Just to note, you don't need `awk` to sum the numbers. `jq -r '.list[] | ... | add'` will do that.

Comment: @Gilles where? I don't have <<<

Comment: Is `.city.sunrise` applied to the same JSON that contains `.list`?

Comment: yes its all in the result from curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind `.city.sunrise` to a variable and use it later:

```bash
jq -r '.city.sunrise as $sunrise | .list[] | select(.dt > $sunrise) | .clouds.all'
```

Note: If calculating the average is all you need `awk` for, consider also doing it inside jq, to save another call to another program, e.g.

```bash
jq -r '.city.sunrise as $sunrise | .list | map(select(.dt > $sunrise) | .clouds.all) | add / length'
```

If there is a chance for `length` to be `0`, catch the error using `?` and `//` as in `(add / length)? // "no data"`.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I haven't seen that binding before. Now I have - from you and @chepner both!

Answer (score 3):

You can bind `.city.sunrise` to a variable in the filter itself.

```
$ curl ... | jq -r '.city.sunrise as $sr | .list[] | select(.dt > $sr) | .clouds.all | add'
<your sum>
```

An `as` expression is a pass-through assignment whose output is the same as its input. The filter argument is applied to the input as well, with the result bound to the variable argument a as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks. Both you and @pmf posted almost simultaneously with the same thought.

Comment: (Im asking both of you in the hope that one of you is still around!) I've tried reading the manual on this but confess I have got lost: I want to add another variable into the mix: city.sunset as $sunset and then to do the select on (.dt > $sunrise and .dt < $sunset). Could you help me out with a way to add this please?

Comment: Just add each variable sequentially: `.city.sunrise as $sunrise | .city.sunset as $sunset | ...`. The `as` expression outputs its input unchanged, just like `.` by itself would.

Comment: Thanks. You know that's exactly how I had done it, but it didn't return anything. After reading your response, though, I ran exactly the same line again and it gave me what I wanted! Magic!